# In-Process communication way

Tags: java, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have 2 programs. I want create task delegation between programs. How can I provide task to other program without RabbitMQ and socket-based server? I want to implement only with vanilla Java way.

I see:

- pipes
- ExecutorService

Comment: *" I want implement only with vanilla Java way."*  Why?

Comment: Vanilla Java = Java 1.0?

Comment: This is the second question I have seen about this today.  I am sure there are probably 1000 ways to communicate between two Java applications without using sockets.  Not sure why you'd want to, but I'll bite.  The first thing that comes to mind is using flat-files.  Have one app monitor a folder, have the other write stuff into the folder.  You will have to do something to let the monitoring app know the sender isn't done yet.  Perhaps write the file with a .tmp extention, which the receiver can ignore, then the sender can simply rename the file when it's done.

Comment: Vanila java is ONLY java. I want create micro server fat jar without other products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a look at [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) for now. In a further future a look into the [Application Isolation API (JSR-121)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=121) might be interesting as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your only two choices is network sockets, file/file-locking, or some JNI you've written to use OS-specific interprocess communication.

I would use a third-party socket-based message queue.

Comment: I agree.  You don't have to send the packets on the wire.  You could, for instance, bind the messaging/sockets to localhost and the packets would never hit the wire.